# What are efficient ways to debug Common Lisp in Emacs and SLIME?

Tags: debugging, emacs, common-lisp, sbcl, slime

I'm wondering what are some efficient ways to debug Common Lisp interactively using Emacs and SLIME.

**What I did before:** As someone who learned C and Python using IDEs (VS and PyCharm), I am used to setting break points, adding watches, and do stepping. But when I started to use CL I found the debugging workflow fundamentally different. I did not find good ways to set break points, step though lines and see how variables change.

The dumb method I used was adding "print" in code and run the code over and over again, which is very inefficient. I know we can "inspect" variables in SLIME but not sure how to do it interactively.

**What I found:** I came across this video on the [development of a Morse code translator](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B_4vhsmRRI) recently, and it shows a complete process of how to debug interactively in SLIME, which has been very informative and enlightening. It is as if we could "talk" to the compiler.

**What I want:** I searched online but found minimal tutorials demonstrating how an experienced Lisper **actually** develop and debug their programs. I am eager to learn such experiences.

- How to debug interactively?
- What are some good practices and tips? How to add breakpoint and step?
- What shortcuts / tools / workflow do you use most frequently / find most useful when debugging?

Comment: Here's a good blog series on [Debugging Lisp](http://malisper.me/2015/07/07/debugging-lisp-part-1-recompilation/).

Comment: @jkiiski That is exact what I wanted! Lots of appreciations! Any other similar resources you came across?

Comment: I just found this book [Common Lisp Recipes](https://www.amazon.com/Common-Lisp-Recipes-Problem-Solution-Approach/dp/1484211774) very helpful for learners: Chapter 16 on debugging and Chapter 17 on optimization.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is a number of things you can do:

- You can trace a function call (see `TRACE` and `UNTRACE` in Common Lisp or `slime-toggle-trace-fdefinition*`). This helps with recursive calls: you can see what you pass and what they return at each level.
- Standard thing: add `(format t ...)` in places. I guess, no need to comment.
- If the code breaks, you will get into debugger. From there you can examine the stack, see what was called and what arguments were passed. See @jkiiski link: it has really great information about it, including `(break)` form that will act as a breakpoint and get you to debugger. **Spoiler alert**: you can change the values in the inspector, you can change and re-compile your code and restart from (almost) any place in the stack.
- Last but not least: to debug macros, you will need `slime-macroexpand-1` (wrapper over `MACROEXPAND-1`) and even better `C-c M-e` for macro stepper.

One last advice: if you are to do a serious debugging, include `(declaim (optimize (debug 3)))` in your file, otherwise some CL implementations have a tendency to optimize away the calls on the stack or make arguments inaccessible.

Comment: ", you will need slime-macroexpand-1 (wrapper over MACROEXPAND-1) and even better C-c M-e for macro stepper. " - care to elaborate on this?

Answer (score 0):

With Common Lisp and Slime you can set break points, look at the values of variables, use an inspector for looking at composite data structures including class instances, and step through your code -- all in principle rather similar to what you are used with IDEs like PyCharm. Rainer Joswig's video *Debugging CL-HTTP, using Clozure Common Lisp, GNU Emacs and SLIME* (https://vimeo.com/77004324) demonstrates all these features, so you can see how it is done in practice with Slime.

One feature I actually greatly prefer in Common Lisp + Slime over debugging with PyCharm is that in the former you can run your program normally and automatically enter the debugger directly at an error and the debugger by default stops where an uncaught exception was raised. By contrast, with PyCharm you run your program, run into an error, then start your program again with the debugger and set manually your breakpoints or ask PyCharm to break at any exception. PyCharm currently does not support to automatically break only at an uncaught exception.